# Memoized implementation of change-making algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, memoization

Recently, I wrote a simple program to solve the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). Rather than the tabular dynamic programming solution (described in the link), I tried to write a solution that uses [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

```
usd = [25, 10, 5, 1]

def make_change(W, denoms=usd):
    """
    Solves the change-making problem where W is
    a given amount of money and denoms 
    is a list of the denominations available

    >>> make_change(6,[3,1])
    (3, 3)
    """

    d = {}

    def inner(W, sol): 
        if W == 0:
            return sol

        if W in d:
            return d[W]

        tmp = []
        for coin in denoms:
            w = W - coin

            if w >= 0:
                tmp.append(inner(w, sol + (coin,)))

        d[W] = min(tmp, key=lambda x : len(x))
        return d[W]
    return inner(W, tuple())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way I should be doing the memoization (i.e. a decorator):

```
def memoize(f):
    d = {}
    def inner(args):
        if args not in d:
            d[args] = f(*args)
        return d[args]
    return inner
```

The above code caches the arguments so they don't get recomputed in future computations. Here, however, I think we only want to cache the solution for a given `W`, and I'm not sure a general purpose decorator like the one above is necessarily correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say the main issue with your code is that you're confusing what the `inner` function is supposed to do:

```
def inner(W, sol): 
    if W == 0:
        return sol   ## return result so far?

    if W in d:
        return d[W]  ## return best result for W?
```

Those are two different kinds of values. If you're just returning "smallest tuple for weight `W`", then `W == 0` should yield `tuple()`. And your recursive step should just be:

```
tmp.append(inner(w) + (coin,))
```

With that, I would rename `tmp`. It's not really a temporary variable, we're actually building up our next possible step. So really something like:

```
next_iteration = (inner(W - coin) + (coin,)
                  for coin in denoms
                  if coin <= W)
```

And for your `key` argument to `min`, you need a function taking one argument and returning a value. You had:

```
key = lambda x: len(x)
```

But `lambda x: len(x)` is the same as `len`. So I'd reduce the whole thing to:

```
d = {0: tuple()} # to avoid the special case of 0
def inner(W):
    if W in d:
        return d[W]

    next_iteration = (inner(W - coin) + (coin,)
                      for coin in denoms
                      if coin <= W)
    d[W] = min(next_iteration, key=len)
    return d[W]

return inner(W)
```

---

For `memoize`, sure, with one minor modification:

```
def memoize(f):
    cache = {}                 # why d?
    def inner(*args):          # <== *args, not args
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return inner
```

And then just:

```
@memoize
def inner(W):
    if W == 0:
        return tuple()

    next_iteration = (inner(W - coin) + (coin,)
                      for coin in denoms
                      if coin <= W)
    return min(next_iteration, key = len)

return inner(W)
```

That does seem nicer. I like it.

Comment: I like this too, just replace the `[` with `(` for lazyness and efficiency. (see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/ )

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with using lists as default values for functions. In your case you don't modify `denoms`, but when default value lists or dictionaries are modified it's actually preserved from one function call to another. For example:

```
nums = [2, 5]

def f(vals=nums):
    vals.append(12)
    print vals
```

Calling `f` repeatedly will produce this:

```
>>> f()
[2, 5, 12]
>>> f()
[2, 5, 12, 12]
>>> f()
[2, 5, 12, 12, 12]
```

Even though your current code doesn't run into that trouble you can easily avoid accidentally creating these issues by making `usd` a tuple. Tuples can't be modified so if you just set `usd` as one you couldn't even accidentally modify it.

```
usd = (25, 10, 5, 1)
```

Also don't use `W` just because the algorithm does. `total`, `total_change` or `total_money` are all better candidates to choose and clearer to understand. Likewise with `d` and `sol`.